# Handling ajax failed response

Tags: jquery, php

My error handling isn't working on this ajax request... Just now my "r" was

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:
simplexml_load_string() [
    <a href='function.simplexml-load-string'>
        function.simplexml-load-string
```

and it didn't execute what's in the `} else {` or even the console.log

```
success: function (r) {

    console.log(r); 
    $('.processing').addClass('hide');              
    if (r.type == 'success') {
        if (r.message.match(/approved/).length > 0) {
            triggerNotification('check', 'Payment has been accepted');
        } else {
            triggerNotification('check', r.message);
        }

        document.location = '/store/order/view?hash='+r.hash;
    } else {
        $('.button').show();

        var msg = 'Unable to run credit card: '+r.message;

        if (parseInt(r.code) > 0) {
            msg = msg+' (Error code: #'+r.code+')';
        }

        triggerNotification('x', msg);
    }
},
```

Comment: can you show the request as well?

Comment: That's a PHP error, not an AJAX error.  The PHP error didn't set an HTTP error header, so your AJAX callback read it as a valid response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a PHP error, not an AJAX error. The PHP error didn't set an HTTP error header, so your AJAX callback read it as a valid response.

It also seems that you are using `dataType: json`, so since the response from PHP was HTML and not JSON, `r` would be `undefined` and that's why `console.log(r)` failed (which probably threw an error in your console, and killed the script).